# What is the best way to collect sanding dust?

Tags: post-processing, safety

I am pretty sure that sanding makes a lot of microplastics, so it would be nice to collect the dust, and melt it to got a blob of plastic again instead of millions of tiny particles. What is the best way for collecting it, do you use any dust extractor, or are there different techniques like sanding wet surfaces and filtering it from water?

Comment: What material? In my experience sanding PLA just doesn't work without water. You quickly hit the glass transition temperature then it just softens.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE It is PLA, maybe later ABS. I figured meanwhile, that it would be the best to treat the water with chemicals to break down the microplastics.

Comment: Melting it has a significant energy impact. As suggested, vacuuming with bags or without bags and then dumping it in the garbage is the best, it will be collected, separated, burned.

Comment: @FarO If you throw it to the garbage it will show up in the food chain. Nobody will recognize microplastics, for them it is just a bag of dust. Burning won't happen either in most countries, they just throw it to a landfill. Better to handle it where you produce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to collect the dust and treat both PLA and ABS with chemicals to completely break them down. That solves the issue and I won't rely on false hopes that somehow it does not end up in the environment.

Comment: What chemical did you find that breaks down PLA?  From my reading, there are few solvents that will affect it...

Comment: @ZeissIkon PLA is a lot easier than ABS. Just google PLA hydrolysis. https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1944/13/9/2111/pdf Looks like a few weeks in 20% HCl is more than enough for PLA. I am not sure about ABS yet. I need to read a lot more about this, probably using google scholar for a few weeks.

Comment: ABS is used for drain pipes, so it's chemically pretty tough stuff.  Most folks who want do something to it use solvents (acetone is top of the list) but you don't want to put those into your own environment, never mind the world -- and they don't break it down anyway; when the solvent evaporates the ABS is left behind.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Yes, maybe I forget about ABS and print only PLA. Though I have an MSc in biochemical engineering, so maybe I'll figure it out later when I need it. Currently it is not a priority.

Comment: FWIW, properties wise, PETG does almost everything ABS does, but is somewhat easier to print (say people who've been at this much longer than I have).  Probably not any easier to break down, though, but easier to re- or up-cycle...

Comment: @ZeissIkon I am a beginner at printing, I really need to see what durability and properties PLA has first. If it is not enough, then I'll check PETG. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Check YouTube for Maker's Muse channel, he had a video where he showed prints that had been outdoors in Australia for a year.  Overall, even PLA held up well.  Don't use it for anything that goes in your car, though; it'll sag above about 120F, which cars in summer easily exceed.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Currently I want to print something like this: https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025267154--Product-Gallery-G7-Laser-Mouse I don't like the shape of current mice, but the sensors and wireless tech are pretty bad in the case of 10+ years old mice like this one. So I decided to print a new shell for my G603. Not sure how long it will take to learn scanning, design, printing. It will be fun. :-)

Comment: For something that will live on your desk, there's no reason to look any further than PLA.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Yes, sweat is the only problem, but food grade PLA is ok I think. I might coat it with epoxy if it is not durable enough. I was thinking on transparent plastic or multiple layers too. It will be a fun project, maybe I print multiple different ones.

Answer (score 4):

As an environmental thing, micro plastics are an urgent problem for ocean life, it’s getting into the entire food chain. With that in mind dumping it down the drain would be the worst, city filtration systems can’t get the tiny bits of plastic before it drains into the ocean. Sanding outside is kind of bad. I sand stuff over a lined waste basket outside, which maybe catches 75% of the dust. Inside (or outside) with a vacuum running would be good, I think best would be a vacuum with disposable bags. Yes it is still micro plastics, but it ends up at the dump, where the soil is already poisoned, and hopefully nowhere near the ocean/waterways, and likely will stay there while it breaks down. PLA takes ~80 years, but ABS takes 1000 years.

The idea of collecting the dust and fusing it sounds like it would be too much hassle to be feasible long term, it’s good, sustainable habits over years that add up.

As a side note, card scraping is a nice way to smooth 3D prints, that doesn’t make fine dust.

Comment: PLA may actually degrade faster as a microplastic than it would as a solid blob.

Comment: And not all the garbage goes to the dump. It is often (and hopefully) burned.

Comment: while down the drain isn't a good idea, the sewage processing  will remove it before it is released.  It's plastic thrown on the ground and washed down the storm drains with the unprocessed rain water that causes the problem, unless you are in a country that doesn't process sewage.